# Google Foo.Bar Challenge Help Minion Salutes

Tags: java

I am working on a foo.bar challenge and have become stuck.  here is the description of the problem:

## > En Route Salute

Commander Lambda loves efficiency and hates anything that wastes time. She's a busy lamb, after all! She generously rewards henchmen who identify sources of inefficiency and come up with ways to remove them. You've spotted one such source, and you think solving it will help you build the reputation you need to get promoted.

Every time the Commander's employees pass each other in the hall, each of them must stop and salute each other - one at a time - before resuming their path. A salute is five seconds long, so each exchange of salutes takes a full ten seconds (Commander Lambda's salute is a bit, er, involved). You think that by removing the salute requirement, you could save several collective hours of employee time per day. But first, you need to show her how bad the problem really is.

Write a program that counts how many salutes are exchanged during a typical walk along a hallway. The hall is represented by a string. For example:
"--->-><-><-->-"

Each hallway string will contain three different types of characters: '>', an employee walking to the right; '<', an employee walking to the left; and '-', an empty space. Every employee walks at the same speed either to right or to the left, according to their direction. Whenever two employees cross, each of them salutes the other. They then continue walking until they reach the end, finally leaving the hallway. In the above example, they salute 10 times.

Write a function answer(s) which takes a string representing employees walking along a hallway and returns the number of times the employees will salute. s will contain at least 1 and at most 100 characters, each one of -, >, or <.

Sample output:

## > Test cases

Inputs:
    (string) s = ">----<"
Output:
    (int) 2

Inputs:
    (string) s = "<<>><"
Output:
    (int) 4

My Code so far:

```
public class Minion_SalutesV1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Test input
    System.out.println(answer("<-->-<--<>-<<-->--<-->"));
    System.out.println(answer("<<><>><>><<><>>>"));
    System.out.println(answer(">----<"));
    System.out.println(answer("<<>><"));
}
public static int answer(String s) {
    //Return a string starting at the first occurrence of '>' and end at the last occurrence of '<+1' 
    String empBound = s.substring(s.indexOf('>'), s.lastIndexOf('<')+1).replaceAll("-", "");
    //Isolate the number of employees walking right
    String rightSaluters = empBound.replaceAll("<", "");
    //Isolate the number of employees walking left
    String leftSaluters = empBound.replaceAll(">", "");
    if(empBound.length() == 2){
        return 2;
    }
    else if (empBound.length() == 3){
        return 4;
    }
    else
    return rightSaluters.length() * leftSaluters.length();
    }
}
```

I have been trying lots of different things on this but have not achieved the correct results yet.

I thought that returning rightSaluters.length() * leftSaluters.length() would give me the desired results.  I feel like I have the right idea by isolating the right and left saluters but I am lost beyond that point.

How do I properly calculate the number of salutes that will take place between the saluters?

Should I make a variable for the number of encounters that will happen then multiply that number by 2?  I realize I am spitballing here but I have been straining my skull over this for days and waited until the last minute to ask for help.

**UPDATE:**  Tried implementation of Jason's answer

```
public class Minion_SalutesV1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Test input
        System.out.println(answer("<-->-<--<>-<<-->--<-->"));
        System.out.println(answer("<<><>><>><<><>>>"));
        System.out.println(answer(">----<"));
        System.out.println(answer("<<>><"));
    }
    public static int answer(String s) {
        //Return a string starting at the first occurrence of '>' and end at the last occurrence of '<+1'
        String empBound = s.substring(s.indexOf('>'), s.lastIndexOf('<')+1).replaceAll("-", "");
        //Isolate the number of employees walking right
        String rightSaluters = empBound.replaceAll("<", "");
        //Isolate the number of employees walking left
        String leftSaluters = empBound.replaceAll(">", "");
        int saluters = rightSaluters.length()+leftSaluters.length();
        System.out.println(saluters);

        for(char c = '>'; c < rightSaluters.length(); c++){
            int count = leftSaluters.length();
            saluters = count*2;
        }
        return saluters * 2;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
8  //remove this
16
11 //remove this
22
2  //remove this
4
3  //remove this
6
```

So it appears the final integer returned for each string is the one I need how do I eliminate the other returns?

Comment: You've posted requirements and code but have asked no *specific* question. Please fix this so that we can know how to answer this. If your question is the broad, "can someone help me", then please read, [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: How do you solve the problem "in your head". What's your strategy? Why do you think your code solves the problem. For example, if the string is "><><", you have 2 left saluters, 2 right saluters, but the answer is not 2 * 2 * 2 = 8. It's 6.

Comment: @JBNizet well initially I figured that by isolating the right saluters and left saluters it would be a simple matter of multiplying the length of their respective strings and returning the value however that did not hold up in every case.  The * 2 on the end of the return is actually a mistake I have edited it out

Comment: It's still wrong without the * 2, as my counterexample shows. This formula is just wrong. Read Jason's answer: that's how I do it myself when counting the number of salutes "in my head".

Comment: Ya something is definitely off, I really appreciate your pointers

Comment: *"how do I eliminate the other returns?"* It's not a "return" but your `System.out.println(saluters);` remove that line and you're done

Comment: Hahaha wow im an idiot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to recognise that minions only salute other minions that are in front of them and are walking towards them.

The algorithm to calculate the number of salutes is:

```
for each '>'
    count the '<' to its right
    add count to the running total
end for

output the running total * 2 (because 2 salutes per meeting)
```

**Edit:** Here's one way to implement my algorithm (not the most efficient code, but a quick-and-dirty first attempt):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Test input
    System.out.println(answer("<-->-<--<>-<<-->--<-->"));
    System.out.println(answer("<<><>><>><<><>>>"));
    System.out.println(answer(">----<"));
    System.out.println(answer("<<>><"));
}

public static int answer(String s) {

    int meetings = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < s.length() - 1; index++) {    // stop one short of the end, since if the last minion is heading right, there won't be anyone in from of him
        if (s.charAt(index) == '>') {
            meetings += countApproachingMinions(s.substring(index + 1));
        }
    }

    return meetings * 2;
}

private static int countApproachingMinions(String hallwayAhead) {
    return hallwayAhead.replaceAll(">", "")    // ignore minions heading the same way
            .replaceAll("-", "")               // ignore spaces
            .length();                         // count the approaching minions
}
```

Comment: Right I knew I was missing something.  When ai setup my empBound substring that is the type of effect I was trying to have to account for minions trailing off either end of the string

Comment: So I tried implementing the algorithm however it is giving me this output: `8
16
11
22
2
4
3
6`  See updated question

Comment: I can not find where I screwed up

Comment: Edited to include a working implementation of my algorithm.

Comment: Man...I was way off.  Thank you for all of your feedback, I really appreciate it.  I am clearly not prepared for a position at google lol...yet

Answer (score 2):

```py
def solution(s):
    pas = 0
    salute = 0
    for x in range(s.find('>'),len(s)-s[::-1].find('<')):
        if(s[x] == '>'):
            pas+=1
        if(s[x] == '<'):
            salute += 2*pas
    return salute
```

**Explanation**

In the above code solution, it will process the string from left to right
and find the index position of '>' from left and '<' from the right.

```
s.find('>'),len(s)-s[::-1].find('<')

< - > - > < - < - >
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    ^         ^
```

minions at positions 0 and 9 never salute others in the above string example. so that we process only from index 2 to 7 (left to right)

if the string is '>' at the current position then increments the **pas** value

```
if(s[x] == '>'):
    pas+=1
```

if the string is '<' at the current position then multiply the **pas** value with 2 and add with a total salute count

```
if(s[x] == '<'):
    salute += 2*pas
```

After the completion of the loop, **salute** value is the total no. of salutes.

```py
#Simulation of the code
< - | > - > < - < | - >
0 1 | 2 3 4 5 6 7 | 8 9
      ^     
current pos = 2
pas = 1
salute = 0

< - | > - > < - < | - >
0 1 | 2 3 4 5 6 7 | 8 9
        ^   
current pos = 3
pas = 1
salute = 0

< - | > - > < - < | - >
0 1 | 2 3 4 5 6 7 | 8 9
          ^   
current pos = 4
pas = 2 
salute = 0

< - | > - > < - < | - >
0 1 | 2 3 4 5 6 7 | 8 9
            ^ 
current pos = 5
pas = 2 
salute = 4  (0 += 2*2 / salute = 2*pas)

< - | > - > < - < | - >
0 1 | 2 3 4 5 6 7 | 8 9
              ^ 
current pos = 6
pas = 2 
salute = 4  (0 += 2*2 / salute = 2*pas)

< - | > - > < - < | - >
0 1 | 2 3 4 5 6 7 | 8 9
                ^ 
current pos = 7
pas = 2 
salute = 8  (4 += 2*2 / salute = 2*pas)
```

Answer (score 1):

A better algorithm that requires only once to go through the entire string.

```
def answer(s):
    # your code herecat 
    multiplier = 0
    salute = 0
    for x in range(len(s)):
        if s[x] is '<':
            multiplier += 1

    for x in range(len(s)):
        if s[x] is '>':
            salute += multiplier
        elif s[x] is '<':
            multiplier -= 1

    ans = salute * 2

    return ans
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it. If you split left and right moving into to different strings and then represent each as a binary number you can use bit wise and &, and bit shift >> operations to simulate the two lines passing each other.

Here is a simple python solution. Note python supports arbitrary length ints, so in another language you might have to pull in a "big int" class for this approach to work.

```python
def answer(s):
    hall_length = len(s)
    hall = s.replace('-', '0')
    left = hall.replace('<', '1').replace('>', '0')
    right = hall.replace('>', '1').replace('<', '0')
    #convert binary strings to ints
    left = int(left, 2)
    right = int(right, 2)
    passes = 0
    for i in range(1, hall_length):
        p = left & (right >> i)#An int whos number of high bits represents the number of passes this step
        p = bin(p).count("1") #Convert to string and count the 1's
        passes = passes + p 
    return int(passes * 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be simpler to implement but looking at the answers, I am confused. This is what I have so far and I tried running a couple of tests and they are passing. What am I missing? Can someone please point me to use-cases that won't work.

```
public static int solution(String s) {
    int left = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char[] charArr = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
      if ('>' == charArr[i]) {
        left++;
      }
      if ('<' == charArr[i]) {
        count += left;
      }
    }
    return count << 1;
}
```